# rating-widget not showing on ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

My problem is that the star rating plugin (http://rating-widget.com/) that im using is not showing when i use an ajax function for searching and filtering.

When the page first loads its working fine the star rating is showing
[image]

but when i use the filter and search function the star rating disappear. This image is when i choose motivational in the dropdownlist
[image]

this is the code for the mainpage where the image, search and filter function is

```
    <div id="div-search" class="wow fadeInDown">
        <div class="form-group inline-buttons">
            <div>
                <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon" style="min-width:150px;">Search</span>
                     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search for name or topic" class="form-control"/>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="min-width:150px;">Filter</span>
                <select name="sortdrpdwn" id="sortdrpdwn" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="motivational">Motivational</option>
                    <option value="technology">Technology</option>
                    <option value="business">Business</option>
                    <option value="leadership">Leadership</option>
                    <option value="innovation">Sales</option>
                    <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                    <option value="healthcare">Health Care</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    <br>
    <div id="order_table" style="overflow-x:auto;"></div>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#sortdrpdwn').change(function()
    {
        var sortdrpdwn = $('#sortdrpdwn').val();  

            $.ajax({  
            url:"filterSp.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{filter:sortdrpdwn},  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
               $('#order_table').html(data);  
            }  
            });  

    });

});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#search_text').keyup(function()
    {
        var searchtext = $('#search_text').val();


            $.ajax({  
            url:"searchSp.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{search:searchtext},  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
               $('#order_table').html(data);  
            }  
            });  


    });

});
</script>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    load_data();  
    function load_data(page)  
    {   
    var sortdrpdwn = $('#sortdrpdwn').val(); 
    var searchtext = $('#search_text').val();

    if(searchtext != '')
    {
        $.ajax({  
        url:"searchSp.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{search:searchtext},  
        success:function(data)  
        {  
           $('#order_table').html(data);  
        }  
        });  
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax({  
        url:"filterSp.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{filter:sortdrpdwn},  
        success:function(data)  
        {  
           $('#order_table').html(data);  
        }  
        });
    }           
    }  


});  
</script>
```

filterSp.php this is the php file that is called when i use filter dropdown list and inside it is the plugin java script for star rating.

```
  <?php  

        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "srdatabase");  

        if(isset($_POST['search_text']))
        {
            $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["search"]);

            $query = "
            SELECT * FROM speakers 
            WHERE speaker_fullname LIKE '%".$search."%'
            OR speaker_specialization1 LIKE '%".$search."%'
            OR speaker_specialization2 LIKE '%".$search."%'
            OR speaker_specialization3 LIKE '%".$search."%'
            OR speaker_specialization4 LIKE '%".$search."%'
            OR speaker_specialization5 LIKE '%".$search."%'
            ";  
        }

        else
        {
            $filter = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["filter"]);

            if($filter == "all")
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM speakers";  
            }

            else if($filter == "motivational")
            {   
                $query = "SELECT * FROM speakers WHERE speaker_specialization1 = 'motivational' OR speaker_specialization2 = 'motivational' OR speaker_specialization3 = 'motivational' ";  
            }

            else if($filter == "technology")
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM speakers WHERE speaker_specialization1 = 'technology' OR speaker_specialization2 = 'technology' OR speaker_specialization3 = 'technology' ";  
            }   

            else if($filter == "business")
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM speakers WHERE speaker_specialization1 = 'business' OR speaker_specialization2 = 'business' OR speaker_specialization3 = 'business' ";
            }

            else if($filter == "leadership")
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM speakers WHERE speaker_specialization1 = 'leadership' OR speaker_specialization2 = 'leadership' OR speaker_specialization3 = 'leadership' ";
            }

            else if($filter == "innovation")
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM speakers WHERE speaker_specialization1 = 'innovation' OR speaker_specialization2 = 'innovation' OR speaker_specialization3 = 'innovation' ";
            }

            else if($filter == "entertainment")
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM speakers WHERE speaker_specialization1 = 'entertainment' OR speaker_specialization2 = 'entertainment' OR speaker_specialization3 = 'entertainment' ";
            }

            else if($filter == "healthcare")
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM speakers WHERE speaker_specialization1 = 'healthcare' OR speaker_specialization2 = 'healthcare' OR speaker_specialization3 = 'healthcare' ";   
            }
        }   
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  


            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)   
            {  
                    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                    { 
                            $output .= '  
                                 <a href="speakerProfile.php?id='.$array["id"].'">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 wow fadeInDown">
                                    <div class="thumbnail"><img class="speakers-image" src="img/'.$array["speaker_image"].'" style="height:220px; min-width:100%;"/>
                                    <div class="caption" style="height:150px; min-width:100%" >
                                        <center>
                                        <h3 class="speakers-name">'.$array["speaker_fullname"].'</h5>
                                        <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization1"].'</p> 
                                        <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization2"].'</p>
                                        <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization3"].'</p>
                                        <br><br>
                                      //The div where the star rating will show
                                        <div class="rw-ui-container" data-urid='.$array["id"].'></div>
                                        </center>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                            ';  
                    }  
            }
            echo $output;  
         ?>
// Star rating javascript        
         <script type="text/javascript">(function(d, t, e, m){

            // Async Rating-Widget initialization.
            window.RW_Async_Init = function(){

                RW.init({
                    huid: "374760",
                    uid: "43310efaa801e10e1e02debca5f5b237",
                    source: "website",
                    options: {
                        "size": "medium",
                        "style": "oxygen",
                        "isDummy": false
                    } 
                });
                RW.render();
            };
                // Append Rating-Widget JavaScript library.
            var rw, s = d.getElementsByTagName(e)[0], id = "rw-js",
                l = d.location, ck = "Y" + t.getFullYear() + 
                "M" + t.getMonth() + "D" + t.getDate(), p = l.protocol,
                f = ((l.search.indexOf("DBG=") > -1) ? "" : ".min"),
                a = ("https:" == p ? "secure." + m + "js/" : "js." + m);
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;              
            rw = d.createElement(e);
            rw.id = id; rw.async = true; rw.type = "text/javascript";
            rw.src = p + "//" + a + "external" + f + ".js?ck=" + ck;
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(rw, s);
            }(document, new Date(), "script", "rating-widget.com/"));
        </script>
```

searchSp.php this is the php file that is called when i use search function and inside it is the plugin java script for star rating.

```
<?php  

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "srdatabase");   

    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["search"]);

    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM speakers 
    WHERE speaker_fullname LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR speaker_specialization1 LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR speaker_specialization2 LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR speaker_specialization3 LIKE '%".$search."%'
    ";  

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)   
    {  
        while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
                $output .= '  
                     <a href="speakerProfile.php?id='.$array["id"].'">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 wow fadeInDown">
                        <div class="thumbnail"><img class="speakers-image" src="img/'.$array["speaker_image"].'" style="height:220px; min-width:100%;"/>
                        <div class="caption" style="height:220px;>
                            <center>
                            <h3 class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_fullname"].'</h5>
                            <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization1"].'</p> 
                            <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization2"].'</p>
                            <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization3"].'</p>
                            <br><br>

                            <div class="rw-ui-container" data-urid='.$array["id"].'></div>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                ';  
           }  
    }
    echo $output;  
 ?>


 <script type="text/javascript">(function(d, t, e, m){

    // Async Rating-Widget initialization.
    window.RW_Async_Init = function(){

        RW.init({
            huid: "374760",
            uid: "43310efaa801e10e1e02debca5f5b237",
            source: "website",
            options: {
                "size": "medium",
                "style": "oxygen",
                "isDummy": false
            } 
        });
        RW.render();
    };
        // Append Rating-Widget JavaScript library.
    var rw, s = d.getElementsByTagName(e)[0], id = "rw-js",
        l = d.location, ck = "Y" + t.getFullYear() + 
        "M" + t.getMonth() + "D" + t.getDate(), p = l.protocol,
        f = ((l.search.indexOf("DBG=") > -1) ? "" : ".min"),
        a = ("https:" == p ? "secure." + m + "js/" : "js." + m);
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;              
    rw = d.createElement(e);
    rw.id = id; rw.async = true; rw.type = "text/javascript";
    rw.src = p + "//" + a + "external" + f + ".js?ck=" + ck;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(rw, s);
    }(document, new Date(), "script", "rating-widget.com/"));</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the  **searchSp.php** you are not passing the rating script to the ajax respond.

Like i said in the comment you can use the sdk, if so there is no need for the javascript your searchSp.php would be like

```
<?php  

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    // Use API site scope.
define('RW_SDK__API_SCOPE', 'site');

// Modify the following definitions to your site details.
define('RW_SDK__SITE_ID',         '__YOUR_SITE_ID__');
define('RW_SDK__SITE_PUBLIC_KEY', '__YOUR_SITE_PUBLIC_KEY__');
define('RW_SDK__SITE_SECRET_KEY', '__YOUR_SITE_SECRET_KEY__');

// Include RatingWidget's SDK.
require dirname(__ROOT__) . '/ratingwidget.php';

// Init SDK with your site details (assumes that the SDK located in same folder of this example).
$rw_api = new \RatingWidget\Api\Sdk\RatingWidget(
    RW_SDK__API_SCOPE,
    RW_SDK__SITE_ID,
    RW_SDK__SITE_PUBLIC_KEY,
    RW_SDK__SITE_SECRET_KEY
);

$item_id = $array["id"]; // Replace that with your rating id.

// If you want the rating to work with Rich-Snippets,
// set the rating class to one of the following values:
//     product, page, blog-post, post, front-post, item
$rating_class = 'product';  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "srdatabase");   

$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["search"]);

$query = "
SELECT * FROM speakers 
WHERE speaker_fullname LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR speaker_specialization1 LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR speaker_specialization2 LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR speaker_specialization3 LIKE '%".$search."%'
";  

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)   
{  
    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
            $output .= '  
                 <a href="speakerProfile.php?id='.$array["id"].'">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 wow fadeInDown">
                    <div class="thumbnail"><img class="speakers-image" src="img/'.$array["speaker_image"].'" style="height:220px; min-width:100%;"/>
                    <div class="caption" style="height:220px;>
                        <center>
                        <h3 class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_fullname"].'</h5>
                        <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization1"].'</p> 
                        <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization2"].'</p>
                        <p class="speakers-name speaker-topics">'.$array["speaker_specialization3"].'</p>
                        <br><br>
                         <div class="rw-ui-container rw-class-'. 
                           $rating_class .' rw-urid-'. $item_id.'">
                          </div>'.
                         $rw_api->EchoAggregateRating($item_id).'
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
            ';  
       }  
}
echo $output;  
?>
```

see [this ->](https://github.com/RatingWidget/php-sdk/blob/master/src/example.html.php)

Comment: thanks for helping sir. but i dont know why its not working, i follow your instruction. first i create a rating.js with the plugin code. and modify the ajax script but its not working. please sir help me fix it

Comment: sir its says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ). its below reloadrating(); and did you consciously remove the "(function(d, t, e, m){" on the top of " window.RW_Async_Init = function(){" in the plugin code?

Comment: i think i make it work sir. by adding the (function(d,t,e,m){ on the plugin code. but my problem now is the star only shows the first time i choose a topic in the filter. And when i choose again the stars in not showing again

Comment: What the name of rating plugin script  !?

Comment: sir like you said i create a file and name it "rating.js"

Comment: did you try using the php sdk, instead of javascript plugin ?! see this https://github.com/RatingWidget/php-sdk/

Comment: um im a bit confuse with that codes. what is the difference with using it. and how to implement it to my current code.

Comment: download this https://github.com/RatingWidget/php-sdk/tree/master/src and put it in your root after that use change the searchSp.php to the one in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154797/discussion-between-m0ns1f-and-red).

Answer (score 0):

Change the height from height:150px to height:220px

Comment: um i dont think the height is the reason.. but thanks for your suggestion.